# What is the best widget for song lyrics?

Tags: music, dashboard-widget, lyrics

I'm looking for a widget that can

- Show the lyrics of the current playing song
- Get the lyrics online if there is none on the music, and save it
- Nice designed

I used to use the Harmonic widget, but it seems it was abandoned

Answer (score 1):

## [SaveThoseLyrics](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/music/savethoselyrics.html) (Freeware)

It looks like it does the same thing as Harmonic.

## [LyricSearch](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/music/lyricsearchwidget.html) (Free)

Allows you to search for lyrics by song. (Don't think this is what you are looking for)

## [Canto Pod](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/music/cantopod.html) (Free)

Allows you to search for a song, then add it to your iTunes library. (Don't think you are looking for this either)

LyricSearch and Canto Pod were lyrics widgets that I found. As I already said, I don't think that's what you are looking for, but I put them there in case you did want to search by song, rather than the current iTunes song. I hope this helps you out.